correct way to add explanatory text to (multiline) display equations in Lyx?
In math textbooks you sometimes find short text alongside each line of a multi-line set of equations.
Something like:
 a = b      (given hypothesis 1)
 a = c^2    (using b=c^2 hypothesis 2)

I can see Lyx can number an equation or specific lines too, but there is no apparent option for "explanatory text".
I could hack it with manual spaced \; or \quad but this feels like a hack and not very lyx.
Is there something like an align environment where one vertical aligns the equals signs, and another vertical left-aligns the explanatory text?

Update - The following is the output of using \quad and \text and as you can see the result is very unsatisfactory.


As LyX user you can find easier make a centered 3x2 table (not a float table) and center it as you center any text. Then just type inline maths or and/or text in cells and align as you want. The result in Cope Preview Pane should be:
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccl}
$a=b$ &  & given fact\tabularnewline
$a=c$ &  & using given fact $b=c$\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\par\end{center}

You can also make some similar with  Eqnarray Environment (Alt+MTE), type the maths and in the math bars use Normal text mode to type the comments. The produced code should be:
\begin{eqnarray*}
a=b &  & \textrm{given fact}\\
a=c &  & \textrm{using given fact \ensuremath{b=c}}
\end{eqnarray*}

Note this will produce another vertical spaces, so check that you will not mix both approaches. Just compare:


Note that with a right click you can change the Eqnarray Environment to AMS Environment → AMS alignat environment, but to produce the same results, you must add two columns and a \qquad to obtain this:

\begin{alignat*}{2}
a=b & \qquad &  & \textrm{given fact}\\
a=c &  &  & \textrm{using given fact \ensuremath{b=c}}
\end{alignat*}

That as far as I can see, for this case produce exactly the same result but is less intuitive.

This approach happens to work if the OP simply wants to display the letters "a", "b", and "c" as is. However, as there's no provision for aligning the = symbols in the first column, this approach won't work if these characters are actually stand-ins for slightly more interesting entities.

@Mico That is why I also indicate how to do it with alignat for the other cases.

@mico's answer was very useful but this one answered regarding the Lyx UI. It turns out what I didn't know before was that both align and alignat can have many columns - the key to solving this!

The align environment can produce two or more columns of aligned material. However, it's not the most suitable environment for the job at hand, as it doesn't permit exerting any control over the amount of whitespace that's inserted between the columns.
Instead, I suggest you employ an alignat environment, a cousin of the align environment. alignat takes one mandatory argument, the number of (structural) columns. For your use case, use alignat{2} and use \qquad ("double \quad") for the space between columns.
The following screenshot shows the outputs of align* and alignat*{2} setups.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' and 'alignat' environments
\usepackage{showframe} % draw framelines around textblock.

\begin{document}

\noindent
Let's write our proof.
\begin{align*}
a &= b && \text{given fact} \\
a &= c && \text{using given fact $b=c$}
\end{align*}
That was a lot of work for something that should have been \dots

\bigskip\bigskip\noindent
Let's rewrite our proof.
\begin{alignat*}{2}
a &= b &\qquad& \text{given fact} \\
a &= c &&       \text{using given fact $b=c$}
\end{alignat*}
That was a lot of work for something that should have been \dots

\end{document}


thanks @Mico - is this something that can be done through the lyx gui?

@Penelope - Doesn't lyx let you insert LaTeX code directly in the document? That's part of the gui, no?

hi @mico - it does, but the idea is to enter exceptional code. I'm planning a book with hundreds of such equations and my preference would be to enter and edit them using the guide, and not by writing code. Lyx lets me enter multi-line aligned equations using the gui, but i guess it doesn't know about alignat.

it turns out that Lyx does provide alignat via the UI. I will experiment with align and alignat. The gap in my knowledge was I didn't know I could have multiple columns!
